# JQuery : Get a value from the result object array

Tags: javascript, jquery

as the result of a function I get a Javascript object. Inside that there is a value for the key called accessToken.

```
   {
    "error": false,
        "data": {
        "key": {
            "validityTime": 3600,
                "consumerKey": "Z0jCb3WElmmKMvegklIAaqIfXWga",
                "tokenDetails":
                "{\"scopes\":[Ljava.lang.String;@862cb97,\"tokenState\":null}",
                "accessToken": "325d7b8b36d5a3e1965ea6b07dd3cda2",
                "appDetails":
                "{\"username\":
                    \"admin\",
                    \"redirect_uris\":
                        \"\",\"validityPeriod\":\"3600\",\"tokenScope\":[Ljava.lang.String;@a32ba44,\"client_name\":\"admin_LastWish343434_SANDBOX\",\"grant_types\":null}",
            "tokenScope": ["am_application_scope", "default"],
            "keyState": "APPROVED",
            "consumerSecret": "9R9xWbEvaEN24aRNd8KN5qyHqjMa",
            "enableRegenarate": true,
            "accessallowdomains": "ALL"
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is display the access token in an alert.

I tried out following. But it do not print the value in the alert box.

```
 window.alert(JSON.stringify(key.tokenDetails.accessToken));
```

How can I get this solved ?

Comment: have you tried key.accessToken?

Comment: That object looks a little.. broken.. can you tidy it up and show a real representation of what you're working with?  This looks like half the object has been stringified and escaped..

Comment: Your JSON is not correct, please check http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the issue by calling the alert function as follows.

```
    var result = {
    "error": false,
        "data": {
        "key": {
            "validityTime": 3600,
                "consumerKey": "Z0jCb3WElmmKMvegklIAaqIfXWga",
                "tokenDetails":
                "{\"scopes\":[Ljava.lang.String;@862cb97,\"tokenState\":null}",
                "accessToken": "325d7b8b36d5a3e1965ea6b07dd3cda2",
                "appDetails":
                "{\"username\":
                    \"admin\",
                    \"redirect_uris\":
                        \"\",\"validityPeriod\":\"3600\",\"tokenScope\":[Ljava.lang.String;@a32ba44,\"client_name\":\"admin_LastWish343434_SANDBOX\",\"grant_types\":null}",
            "tokenScope": ["am_application_scope", "default"],
            "keyState": "APPROVED",
            "consumerSecret": "9R9xWbEvaEN24aRNd8KN5qyHqjMa",
            "enableRegenarate": true,
            "accessallowdomains": "ALL"
        }
    }
}

window.alert(result.data.key.accessToken);
```

It successfully printed the accessToken